# Conditional field color

Tags: php

I would like to assign field colors like  to the field "status". if the mysql filed is "yes" then it should be green, if "no" then it should be red. Who can assist? Many thanks in advance. below you will see my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members";   
$result = mysql_query($query);     
while (list($id,$name,$status) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{ 
  echo("<tr><td>$name</td><td>$status</td></tr>\n"); 
}
```

Comment: It's a simple if statement, `if($status == 'yes){ $color == 'green'; }`, then color green, and so on.

Comment: Side note: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` function, use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can try -

```
echo("<tr style='color:" 
. (($status=='no') ? 'red' : 'green') 
. "'><td>$name</td><td>$status</td></tr>\n");
```

or also can do using an `array` of colors -

```
$colors= array('yes' => 'green', 'no' => 'red');
echo("<tr style='color:" 
. $colors[$status] 
. "'><td>$name</td><td>$status</td></tr>\n");
```

Comment: Just one suggestion, I think we should treat $status as Boolean value here.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu It depends on how it is saved or configured.

Comment: yeh, I am talking about that, "Should we encourage / advice him to store $status as a Boolean value ?? "

Comment: What if it is an enumeration?

Comment: he has said it has two value yes or no, is it not Boolean TRUE and Boolean FALSE ??

Answer (score 1):

> Considering $status is only yes or no, it should be treated as Boolean
>   value. I assume this is an Boolean value.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members";   
$result = mysql_query($query);     
while (list($id,$name,$status) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{ 
if($status){
      echo("<tr style='color:green'><td>$name</td><td>$status</td></tr>\n"); 
  } else {
      echo("<tr  style='color:red' ><td>$name</td><td>$status</td></tr>\n"); 
  }
}
```

Considering it to be Boolean we can modify **Sougata's cod**e to be like .

```
echo("<tr style='color:" 
. ($status ? 'red' : 'green') 
. "'><td>$name</td><td>$status</td></tr>\n");
```

> You should also use mysqli or PDO as mysql_* are deprecated.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and closed in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `mysql_*` extension its deprecated and close in PHP 7, use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Here is the complete example of your code by using MYSQLi Object Oriented:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['status'] == 'YES'){
        ?>
            <tr><td style="color:green;"><?=$row['name']?></td><td style="color:green;"><?=$row['status']?></td></tr>
        <?php   
        }
        else{
        ?>
            <tr><td style="color:red;"><?=$row['name']?></td><td style="color:red;"><?=$row['status']?></td></tr>
        <?php   
        }
    }    
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

You just need to add check inside the while loop if status is `YES` use `green` color else `red` color